# How to use a digest-aware asset for default_url in rails4?

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, helper

In rails 3, to use an asset from the pipeline as the `default_url` in *carrierwave*'s uploader, you did something like the following:

```
class MyUploader
  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

In rails 4, the pipeline has been abstracted into the *sprockets-rails* gem/railtie, so the above will give you:

> uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers

Looking at the *sprockets-rails* gem, the replacement helper would seem to be `Sprockets::Rails::Helper`. But with this module included, `asset_path("fallback/default.png")` returns, simply:

```
# wrong:
"/fallback/default.png"
```

*not* the asset- and digest-aware URL that I expect:

```
"/assets/fallback/default-b3beee1588afe2ae582c64888cd007db.png"
```

How can I get the correct `asset_path` behavior outside of a view?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Don't `include` anything. Use the *helper proxy* instead, like this:

```
def default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
end
```

### The Gory Details:

`Sprockets::Rails::Helper` makes use of a sprockets manifest to properly locate and digest assets. Once it got abstracted into a gem for rails 4, this manifest started getting set by the railtie. So simply `include`-ing the module's methods into our class wasn't enough to pull that manifest in, and `asset_path` (mis)behaved accordingly.

Thankfully, there is the [oft-overlooked](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views) `ActionController::Base.helpers` class method:

> Provides a proxy to access helpers methods from outside the view.

Like the docs say, it acts as a *helper proxy* and is probably what *should* have been used for this purpose from the begining (including helper modules into your namespace runs the risk of polluting your class with unused methods and potentially overwriting stuff, so using the proxy is the better alternative).

There might yet be some equivalent of `Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper` that hacks enough together to give `Sprockets::Rails::Helper` what it needs to get the job done. But the proxy is, IMHO, a much more elegant solution. So I've stopped searching.

Comment: Of note is that the file has to actually exist for the path to be generated correctly. If the file doesn't exist in `/app/images/fallback/default.png` (for a default version), the wrong path will be generated.

Comment: @sevenseacat your comment helped me debug this same issue, except the files were there, but I just needed to bounce the server after adding them. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveRapin glad I could help :)